# Hibernate reflection fails on save

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

After doing `mvn deploy` in this project and `mvn -U clean install` in another project that imports a package from this one I get the following error when saving an entity:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice.description] by reflection for persistent property [is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice#description] : is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice@384fb0b8; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice.description] by reflection for persistent property [is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice#description] : is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice@384fb0b8

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice.description] by reflection for persistent property [is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice#description] : is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice@384fb0b8
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4669)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice.description to is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
```

This has happened before and it took a former employee days to figure out that it had something to do with the class being loaded twice or something really weird. All I know is that it required no changes in the code to fix this last time.

I've tried removing the classes from .m2 and target and rebuilding but no luck.

I'm using Intellij as well if that's relevant.

Any ideas?

---

edi:

I've fixed this issue but I can't really explain why it worked. Running the uberjar with `java -jar` worked and after that it just worked again in Intellij.

Answer (score 2):

This is your actual exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
   Can not set java.lang.String field 
        is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice.description
     to is.godo.server.property.server.entity.Invoice
```

Did you do any recent schema changes? Hibernate thinks that this field is a String, but you're trying to put in an actual Invoice. Did you forget to run the metadata generator? Are you storing hibernate objects in a session? If so, try changing the serialization version.

Comment: No changes to the schema and no sessions. The application fails when run in Intellij but works fine when run with java -jar. After running it with java -jar it works again in Intellij.

Comment: As for the metadata generator I'm using Spring Boot and I'm not that familiar with its internals or Hibernate.

Comment: Maybe IntelliJ is too.. intelligent - after running it with IntelliJ (aafter it fails), check to see if there are any generated-sources or generated-classes in the `target` directory.